# ssh: connect to host abc-int.xxx.com port 22: Connection timed out Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, sftp

While connecting to a remote server from linux hosted in different server using below command,
`sftp Q_ROOTS@abc-int.xxx.com`, where *Q_ROOTS* is the username , i am getting the following error:

```
rootssys@GBBVL072:>sftp Q_ROOTS@abc-int.xxx.com,
Connecting to abc-int.xxx.com,...
ssh: connect to host sfx-int.nexperia.com port 22: Connection timed out
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like some firewall is dropping the packets of your connection request without sending a reject back to your client.

Change the firewall config to allow connections to port 22 of 'abc-int.xxx.com'.